# Angular directive not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing an angular dropdown list with bootstrap.  I have created a directive where the user selects a menu option from the dropdown and alerts the user.

I have created a plnkr here

http://plnkr.co/edit/tw3O5ihT7YB79BcAGlsh?p=preview

```
  (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('plunker').directive('exportData', exportData);

  function exportData() {
    var controller = function() {

        var vmd = this;

        vmd.exportAction = [{
          id: 1,
          action: 'Export all -> excel',
          visble: true
        }, {
          id: 2,
          action: 'Export selected -> excel',
          visble: true
        }, {
          id: 0,
          action: '',
          visble: true,
          divider: true
        }, {
          id: 3,
          action: 'Export all -> pdf',
          visble: true
        }, {
          id: 4,
          action: 'Export selected -> pdf',
          visble: true
        }];

        function activate() {} //activate

        activate();

        vmd.selectedExport = function(action) {
          alert("you selected " + action.action);
        };

      } //controller

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
//      scope: {
//        datasource: '=',
//      },
      controller: controller,
      controllerAs: 'vmd',
      templateUrl: 'exportData.html',
      bindToController: true
        //link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        //    });
    };
  };
}());
```

Any ideas, and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing `<script src="exportData.js"></script>` in the plunkr example http://plnkr.co/edit/YH4A5bb1o3ss5ECD0j8g